# Mask RCNN: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, boolean

I am working on a project, and I need to train Mask RCNN regarding to SpaceNet Dataset.

So, When I try to train my model, lots of warnings and errors show up.

The Error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a73fb1f7a961> in <module>
      8             learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,
      9             epochs=10,
---> 10             layers='heads')
     11 
     12 # Training - Stage 2

~\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py in train(self, train_dataset, val_dataset, learning_rate, epochs, layers, augmentation, custom_callbacks, no_augmentation_sources)
   2372             max_queue_size=100,
   2373             workers=workers,
-> 2374             use_multiprocessing=True,
   2375         )
   2376         self.epoch = max(self.epoch, epochs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1656             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1657             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1658             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1659 
   1660     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\Anaconda3\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    179             batch_index = 0
    180             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
--> 181                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
    182 
    183                 if not hasattr(generator_output, '__len__'):

~\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py in data_generator(dataset, config, shuffle, augment, augmentation, random_rois, batch_size, detection_targets, no_augmentation_sources)
   1707                     load_image_gt(dataset, config, image_id, augment=augment,
   1708                                 augmentation=augmentation,
-> 1709                                 use_mini_mask=config.USE_MINI_MASK)
   1710 
   1711             # Skip images that have no instances. This can happen in cases

~\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py in load_image_gt(dataset, config, image_id, augment, augmentation, use_mini_mask)
   1263     _idx = np.sum(mask, axis=(0, 1)) > 0
   1264     mask = mask[:, :, _idx]
-> 1265     class_ids = class_ids[_idx]
   1266     # Bounding boxes. Note that some boxes might be all zeros
   1267     # if the corresponding mask got cropped out.

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 650
```

The warnings are:

> ERROR:root:Error processing image {'id': 219, 'source': 'yapi', 'path': None, 'width': 650, 'height': 650}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\MUSTAFAAKTAS\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py", line 1710, in data_generator
>       use_mini_mask=config.USE_MINI_MASK)
>     File "C:\Users\MUSTAFAAKTAS\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py", line 1266, in load_image_gt
>       class_ids = class_ids[_idx]
>   IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 650

--

> ERROR:root:Error processing image {'id': 448, 'source': 'yapi', 'path': None, 'width': 650, 'height': 650}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\MUSTAFAAKTAS\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py", line 1710, in data_generator
>       use_mini_mask=config.USE_MINI_MASK)
>     File "C:\Users\MUSTAFAAKTAS\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py", line 1266, in load_image_gt
>       class_ids = class_ids[_idx]
>   IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 650

--

> Also there are warnings for image_id: 219-348-444-448-3986-3023

Answer (score 1):

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 650

This error indicates that you are trying to pass 1 class ids to place that expects 650 classes.

```
def load_mask(self, image_id):
    """Load instance masks for the given image.

    Different datasets use different ways to store masks. Override this
    method to load instance masks and return them in the form of am
    array of binary masks of shape [height, width, instances].

    Returns:
        masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
            a binary mask per instance.
        class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
    """
    # Override this function to load a mask from your dataset.
    # Otherwise, it returns an empty mask.
    logging.warning("You are using the default load_mask(), maybe you need to define your own one.")
    mask = np.empty([0, 0, 0])
    class_ids = np.empty([0], np.int32)
    return mask, class_ids
```

This is the load_mask function that takes in an array of object classes as the class_ids. You have to implement it in your own way so that for each mask there is a corresponding object class. This for example is how I did it:

First I extract bounding boxes and their respective labels from an xml file created with labelimg:

```
# extract bounding boxes from an annotation file
def extract_boxes(self, filename):
    # load and parse the file
    tree = ElementTree.parse(filename)
    # get the root of the document
    root = tree.getroot()
    # extract each object
    boxes = list()
    for object in root.findall('.//object'):
        box_class_list = list()
        #find bbox coordinates
        for box in object.findall('.//bndbox'):
            xmin = int(box.find('xmin').text)
            ymin = int(box.find('ymin').text)
            xmax = int(box.find('xmax').text)
            ymax = int(box.find('ymax').text)
            coors = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
            box_class_list.append(coors)
        #get the name of the object class corresponding to the bbox
        for name in object.findall('.//name'):
            box_class_list.append(name.text)
        #append the box coors and respective name to a list
        boxes.append(box_class_list)
    # extract image dimensions
    width = int(root.find('.//size/width').text)
    height = int(root.find('.//size/height').text)
    return boxes, width, height
```

Then use the extracted data in the load_mask as follows:

```
def load_mask(self, image_id):
    # get details of image
    info = self.image_info[image_id]
    # define box file location, here the annotation dir in project dir
    path = info['annotation']
    # load XML
    boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(path)
    # create one array for all masks, each on a different channel
    masks = zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
    # create masks
    class_ids = list()
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        box = boxes[i][0]
        row_s, row_e = box[1], box[3]
        col_s, col_e = box[0], box[2]
        masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 1
        class_ids.append(self.class_names.index(boxes[i][1]))

    return masks, asarray(class_ids, dtype='int32')
```

Sorry for not writing a fully functional example but I have little time atm. Hope this helps. Also, this example does not have any actual masks extracted, fyi, just bboxes and classes.